# Delimiting with getline()

Tags: c++

I want to split the strings with delimiter , using getline()

```
 std::istringstream args("["2,3", 3]"); 
 std::string temp;
 std::string arg;
 std::vector<std::string> out_args;
 while(getline(args, temp, ',')) {
 }
```

my problem is that getline() taking "2,3" also splitting it, I want to split only if delimiter , is not in double quotes.

Comment: std::istringstream args("["2,3", 3]"); Does this even compile?

Comment: *I want to split only if delimiter , is not in double quotes*  You're going to need something a lot more complex the `getline()`.  Parsing quoted strings is not easy.  All `getline()` does is split the data by the delimiter regardless of its context.

Comment: Have you tried **"2\,"** ?

Comment: I tried with \, it did not work @moi

Comment: You need to use `"[\"2,3\", 3]"`, or `R"(["2,3", 3])"` in C++11 and later